# Placing a player on a Board and Moving them in Python

Tags: python

Im currently trying to add a player to a board in python to be able to command the player but I cant seem to figure it out.

```
def GenPlayer(level):
  player = {}
  player['name'] = GenName()
  player['history'] = GenHistory() #history
  player['attack'] = DieRoller(3,6) + DieRoller(level,4)
  player['defense'] = DieRoller(3,6) + DieRoller(level,4)
  player['health'] = DieRoller(5,6) + DieRoller(level,4)
  player['row'] = 0
  player['col'] = 0
  character =(player['name']) + ("Health: "+str(player['health'])) + (" Defense: "+str(player['defense'])) + (" Attack:  "+str(player['attack']))
  return character


def CreateBoard():
    board =  []
    while True:
        x = int(input("Number of Rows:  "))
        y = x
        break
    for row in range(0,x):
        board.append(["()"]*y)
    return board

def ShowBoard(board):
    for row in board:
        print(" ".join(row))

def PlacePlayer(board,player):
    row = DieRoller(1,6)
    col = DieRoller(1,6)
    board[row][col] = 'player'
    return board,player
print(PlacePlayer(ShowBoard(CreateBoard()),GenPlayer(1)))
```

I keep getting this error when trying this code:

Exception has occurred: TypeError
'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: `player['row'] = DieRoller(1,6)` What is `player`. Did you mean `row = DieRoller(1,6); col = DieRoller(1,6); board[row][col] = "@"`?

Comment: Ive got a separate file that generates a random player Im trying to put the generated player onto the board

Comment: don't you get any error message? always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I updated the question now

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place the `player` object at the selected position, remove the quote marks:

```
board[row][col] = player
```

Update:

A player object is a dictionary, so you need to place the `player['name']`  on the board to be able to print it in the `ShowBoard()` function you have, as the function uses `.join()` , which is a string method. I made a slight change to `PlacePlayer()`, and simplified the code to make it a bit easier to understand what's happening:

```
def PlacePlayer(board,player):
    row = 5
    col = 4
    board[row][col] = player['name']
    return board

newboard= CreateBoard()
characterDescripiton , playerobject = GenPlayer(1)
boardafterPlacePlayer =  PlacePlayer(newboard,playerobject)
ShowBoard(boardafterPlacePlayer)
```

Comment: Could it be this line of code that is messing it up?

print(PlacePlayer(ShowBoard(CreateBoard()),GenPlayer(1)))

Comment: @MEGTFOD12, `PlacePlayer()` needs the board object, and the player object passed to it to have the desired output. What is the output of show board? Can you present the code for all functions and the error message?